# Listar posts por categoria

Tags: php, wordpress, post

Eu tenho vários posts e alguns deles possuem uma categoria chamada "Destaque" e os demais estão sem categoria, o que preciso fazer é listar todos esses posts, sendo que os primeiros sempre precisam ser os da categoria "Destaque" independente de quando foram postados.

O código que eu tenho é simplesmente listando todos os posts, já tentei utilizar o comando `oderby` só que sem sucesso, posso ter feito errado também.

Meu código é o seguinte:

```
    <?php $posts = get_posts( array('post_type'=>'sala', 'numberposts'=>-1, 'order'=>'ASC') ); ?>
    <?php setup_postdata($post);?>

         <?php foreach($posts as $post):

                   /* mostro salas */

         <?php endforeach;?>
```

Não tenho muita experiência com o Wordpress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Então, as `taxonomias` do Wordpress não foram feitas para ordenar e sim para agrupar posts. Elas não são muito recomendadas para ordenar pois o custo de processamento é alto e dependendo da quantidade de registros que o seu site tiver vão o deixar consideravelmente mais lento.

O que eu te recomendo é usar [Meta Data](https://codex.wordpress.org/Metadata_API), pois o Wordpress suporta [ordenar por meta data](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) nativamente.

Porém, se ainda assim você quer ordenar por `taxonomia`, você iria ter que escrever a sua própria `query`, pra isso esse [artigo](http://scribu.net/wordpress/sortable-taxonomy-columns.html) mostra alguns exemplos de como alcançar tal objetivo.